# Как одновременно с открытие вкладки браузера запустить таймер?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Используется: C#, WebDriver

СЦЕНАРИЙ
    1. Открываем браузер
    2. Переходим по ссылке
      Запускаем Таймер (секундомер)
    3. Ожидание 5 сек
    4. Закрываем вкладку
     Останавливаем Таймер (секундомер)

Формат значения таймера:
     - в виде одной цифры. Пример: 1 мин 30 сек в таймере отображается как 90 сек.
     - таймер работает по возрастанию (т.е. 1 сек, 2 сек.. А не 2 сек, 1 сек.)
Данные Таймера отображаются в label.

Попробовал так..

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Windows.Forms;   
using OpenQA.Selenium;   
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;  
using System.Threading; // потоки  
using System.Threading.Tasks; // потоки

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
        i++ ;  
        label9.Text = i.ToString();  
 }  
private void mythread1()  
{  
timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
} 
private void mythread2()
{
i++;
label9.Text = i.ToString();        
}

private void mythread3()
{
timer1.Stop();
}
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// ПОТОКи
Thread thread1 = new Thread(mythread1);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(mythread2);
Thread thread3 = new Thread(mythread3);
thread1.Start();
thread2.Start(); 
// ОТКРЫТЬ БРАУЗЕР
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions co = new             
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
co.BinaryLocation = @"c:\soft\UD\GoogleChromePortable\1_1\GoogleChromePortable_1.exe";
co.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=c:\soft\UD\GoogleChromePortable\1_1\Data\profile\");
 Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(co);
 Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.yandex.ru"); // ПЕРЕХОД. СПИСОК ВИДЕО
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // пауза
 Browser.Close();
 thread3.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для замеров [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
...
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start(); // запускаем
Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.yandex.ru"); // ПЕРЕХОД. СПИСОК ВИДЕО
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // пауза
stopwatch.Stop(); // останавливаем
var time = stopwatch.Elapsed; // значение затраченного времени
...
```